# Receiving System.IndexOutOfRangeException Error

Tags: arrays, vb.net, directory, indexoutofrangeexception

I wrote code that counts lines in text file and creates folders with lines.
For example If there is text like this

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

The folders would be made with those texts. Here's the code that throws `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` Error

```
Dim lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(TempPath & "EAB\EAB.txt").Length
For i = 0 To lineCount Step 1
    Dim RAL As String = File.ReadAllLines(TempPath & "EAB\EAB.txt")(i)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(startPath & "\Test\" & RAL & "\")
Next
```

It creates folders perfectly but whenever it finishes creating folder it throws `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` Error In `File.ReadAllLines`. Can anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of [What is IndexOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception is caused because you are trying to read the array at position `lineCount`, when in fact, you should never read past `lineCount - 1`, which is that last position of the array.

So changing your `For` statement to this would avoid the exception:

```
For i = 0 to lineCount - 1
```

However, I would really advise against the way you have setup your code right now, because you are actually re-reading the *entire* file *every time* you invoke `File.ReadAllLines()`, which you do even inside the loop.  For a big file, the performance impact would be huge.  That's not good and completely unnecessary.

Instead, using a `For Each` loop would be a much cleaner way of writing this:

```
For Each RAL In File.ReadAllLines(TempPath & "EAB\EAB.txt")
    Directory.CreateDirectory(startPath & "\Test\" & RAL & "\")
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I love it work it. I should study using For Each. For me, it's a little bit hard

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your code structure like such

```
Dim lines as String() = File.ReadAllLines(...);
Dim count as Integer = lines.Length;

for i as Integer = 0 To count Step 1
   Dim thisLine as String = lines(i)

   //Stuff
next
```

This is better because the array is loaded into memory first and the length of the array is not calculated with every iteration of the `for` loop

Happy Holidays

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped me a lot!